# how do i upload my React project to GitHub without including the node modules folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github, npm

> I want to upload my React Project to GitHub but I want to exclude the node modules folder, how do  I do that ?

Comment: Add a `.gitignore` file to the repository and put `node_modules` in it. See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 4):

Create a .gitignore file at the root of your project and add this line:

/node_modules

You can learn more here: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `.gitignore` file at the root folder/directory of your project and the add `node_modules` folder to ensure that it is not pushed to your remote repository.

[image]